Safari Web Extension background script becomes unresponsive after 30 seconds
Overview
I'm experiencing a Safari Web Extension issue where the non-persistent background script seems to crash after 30 seconds even when the content script is messaging it.
Here is a minimal-reproducible example. When running in an emulator, the background script will stay responsive forever. However, when running on a physical device, the background script becomes non-responsive after 30 seconds of activity. It never becomes responsive again until I toggle the extensions enable/disable toggle, after which it stays active for 30 seconds and then crashes again.
Steps to Reproduce

Clone this repo
Open in Xcode and run targeting a physical device
Open Safari on the device and enable the extension
Open a new tab and navigate to https://www.google.com
From your Mac, open the Safari Web Inspector and navigate to the extension's background page
You will see messages being sent from the content script to the background script every 1 second
After 30 seconds, the background script will stop receiving messages. Trying to use the console to interact with the background script, e.g., typing console.log("hello") will show that it is no longer responsive.

Additional Findings
If you look through the content script code you'll see that I am calling runtime.sendMessage every 1 second which always causes the background script to crash after 30 seconds.
I started to play with the 1 second interval to see if it behaved differently. Increasing it to 2 seconds caused a crash after 15 calls (also 30 seconds). Increasing the interval to 3 seconds caused a crash after 10 calls (also 30 seconds).
Increasing to 4 seconds causes the background script to behave how I'd expect... that is it never crashes and is able to respond to the sendMessage request forever.

In manifest.json, "persistent": false is set, but why not try setting it to true?

With Manifest Version 3, all IOS Safari Web Extension background scripts must be non-persistent.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/optimizing_your_web_extension_for_safari#3743241

There is a GitHub issue in my MRE repository that has some relavent information!

This issue appears to be fixed in iOS 17.6 Beta, according to Apple's Safari release notes:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-17_6-release-notes

I am also a browser extension developer and since the last iOS updates (17.4 and above), I have the issue you are mentioning.
Contrary to you, my extension is running with Manifest V2 but I experience the same "crash" of my background script after 30s exactly: it becomes totally unresponsive.
I tried the method suggested in this post but it didn't fix my issue (the described method is more adapted to Manifest V3 but I tried to adapt it to V2).
If anyone finds a solution/patch or has any lead on how to solve this, please share!

Coming back to this discussion. After investigation, I have found three possible ways of patching this issue, none of which is ideal, while Apple developers release a fix for it.

Move all the logic to the content script: this is very time-consuming, unsecured, and sometimes not even possible as some APIs are not accessible through the background script. This also means that you can't synchronize states between tabs.
Create a queue to send at most 1 message every 4 seconds. As mentioned in the thread above, it seems that more than 1 message every 3 seconds causes the background script to crash/be unresponsive after 30s. But having 1 message every 4 seconds or more seems to keep it alive indefinitely. The problem is that this approach won't work in cases where many messages need to be sent quickly, and the best scenario is a degraded UX.
Reload the extension every X seconds, X < 30. This may be the most effective patch for this issue, although a bit violent. The idea is to rely on the API browser.runtime.reload to programmatically reload the extension before the background script gets frozen indefinitely. I tested it and it works: by restarting the extension regularly, I was able to get my background script living indefinitely.

Regarding option 3, there are some caveats to be aware of:

Sometimes, I end up in a weird state where the background script doesn't seem to be loaded (I can't see it in the Safari dev tools). Opening a new tab kills it and reloads it which almost always fixes the issue. In addition, this does not happen very often. I am wondering if the issue is not exacerbated by the fact that I have the Safari dev tools opened.
This approach won't work if you are injecting content scripts statically (ie you declare them in your manifest.json). In that case, every reload of the extension injects a new content script in your active tab, and it doesn't discard the old script. Even if you find a way to only execute one content script logic (which I did), you end up overloading the memory of the phone which results in Safari being super buggy and displaying error pages (on my iPhone 15 Pro, it happens after roughly 80/100MB of content script was injected).
To overcome the problem of multiple scripts being injected, you need to rely on a dynamic injection process (different injection policies are well-explained on MDN). This is not very difficult to implement, you just need to remove your content scripts declaration in the manifest and use the API browser.scripting.executeScript (MV3) or browser.tabs.executeScript (MV2) to load your content script dynamically. You then need to load your script at the right moment, for instance after the DOMContentLoaded event of the webpage (this can be done using browser.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded).

I hope this is clear. If you test option 3 and make it work and/or find issues, I am happy to have your feedback!

IOS 17.6 beta was recently launched and rumor is that this issue has been addressed. I haven't had time to test it yet.
For us, we went with option 1 last week and it's been going well. Our use case is such that we don't need the background script for much, but we are missing some features until it is stable e.g., tab activated events, window focus events, etc.

While now on iOS 17.6 beta and iOS 18 beta the background.js service_worker will not stop working after 30 seconds, it will still sometime stop working if the user exits safari, do other things on the device or the device is idle/locked for some time. When you get back into Safari, you'll get to the same state of the service worker not in operational state. If you swipe up to terminate Safari and relaunch, it will be back in operational state.
